# python code to check prime number consider (55,25 ) is prime number

Tags: python, numbers, primes

[snap shot for code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njhEz.jpg) 
the python program to check prime number in list of number consider 55 and 25 as prime number which is actually not prime because 55/5=11 and reminder is zero 
so what problem in code

```
def check_prime(n):
    for i in range(2,n,1):
        if(n%i)==0:
            return  1
        else :
            return 0

numbers=[51,52,53,54,55,13,407,508,11,17,60,12,19,25,30,]
for j in numbers:
    if check_prime(j)==1:
        print("the {} is not prime".format(j))
    else:
        print("th {} is prime".format(j))
```

Comment: Can you please past your code here?

Comment: May I suggest flipping the return values? It has nothing to do with your issue, but if you see the function name check_prime as a question of "is this a prime number?", then you'd prefer a return value of 1 to be yes and 0 to be no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a logical error in `check_prime` function, try this :

```
def check_prime(n):
    for i in range(2, n, 1):
        if (n % i) == 0:
            return True
    return False


numbers = [51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 13, 407, 508, 11, 17, 60, 12, 19, 25, 30, ]
for j in numbers:
    if check_prime(j):
        print("the {} is not prime".format(j))
    else:
        print("th {} is prime".format(j))
```

Comment: ok thank very much but why code return this error with only number that accept dividable by 5

Answer (score 0):

because, you put return in your function, and for this reason your function only do the first evaluation in other your function only return if a number is odd or ever, because only evaluate when i = 2, your function has to be.

```
def check_prime(n):
   for i in range(2,n):
      if(n%i)==0:return False
   return True
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function returns after a single iteration, cancelling the effect of your for loop. You want to return when finding its not a prime number, but you need to continue looping through all numbers before you can say a prime number is prime. Also, flipped the return values to make more intuitive sense.

```
def check_prime(n):
    for i in range(2,n,1):
        if(n%i)==0:
            return  0
    return 1
```

Comment: but why return number 11 as prime number 19 as prime a

Comment: Because they all fail on x%2==0 and then stop looping, so they are all labeled prime. For 11 and 19 this is correct, but not for 25 and 55.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the return in your loop conditional. It will exit after a single loop in this case, which is why you are seeing it return false positives.